# Writing data into a bmp file

Tags: objective-c, bitmap, bmp

I'm currently interfacing an oscilloscope (agilent DSO7104B) in objective-c, and my goal is to get the image displayed on the screen of the oscilloscope.
The scope sends me the bmp data and then i put it into an empty file and I try to open it, but the image is displayed weirdly, with a kind of offset. Here is my code :

```
NSString *str = @":DISP:DATA? BMP, SCR, GRAY\r\n";
NSData *strData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[outputStream write:(uint8_t *)[strData bytes] maxLength:[strData length]];

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];

uint8_t buf[1024];
[((NSInputStream *) inputStream) read: buf maxLength: 1024];

uint8_t *buff;
buff=malloc(2546752);
memset (buff, 0, 2546752);
//buff=malloc(2551000);
//memset (buff, 0, 2551000);

int len;
[self makeNewFile];
int count=0;
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
    len = [((NSInputStream *) inputStream) read: &(buff[count]) maxLength: 318344];
    count=count+318344;
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
}
//[self printImage: buff: 2546742];
[self printImage: buff: 2546752];
```

And here is the printImage function :

```
- (void) printImage: (uint8_t*) buff : (int) len{
NSFileManager *manager;
manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSData *buffer;
NSFileHandle *fin, *fout;
fin = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:instancePath];
fout = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:instancePath];

if([manager fileExistsAtPath:instancePath]==NO){
    NSLog(@"Unreachable path");
}
if([manager fileExistsAtPath:instancePath]==YES){
    NSLog(@"File ready");
}

//buffer = [NSData dataWithBytes:&(buff[10]) length:2546742-10];
buffer = [NSData dataWithBytes:&(buff[10]) length:2546752-10];
//buffer = [NSData dataWithBytes:buff length:2546742];

[fout writeData:buffer];
[fin closeFile];
[fout closeFile];
```

All the commented code is some testcode that i don't use anymore.
The scope sends me 2546752 bytes of data, including a 10 bytes header that must not be in the bmp file. I have to get it by 8 samples (the for loop) because the telnet buffer is too small otherwise.
The first reading (buf 1024 bytes) is here to clear the inputstream of any data that the scope may send before the image.
I'm sure that i get the good beginning data because, if i open the file in a hexadecimal editor i can see the bitmap header ("BM..."), but i think i don't get the "core" of the file as i should...
Edit : Two years later, still haven't found the problem... Gave up